# Building a function that imports value for the neighbor cell of a matching cell from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I’m trying to create a two-way communication “sync” system for neighboring cells with a matching cell between 2 separate Google Sheets Spreadsheets. So for example, 2 Spreadsheets called “A” and “B” will both have a column in them called “Phone number” that will both have the same values, and I want to sync the data of other columns from that row’s matching phone number from the other sheet.

So if Spreadsheet A and B both have a row, and they both have the value “1112223333” in the Phone Number column, but only Spreadsheet A has the value “example@example.com” in that row’s email column, I want to make it so that “example@example.com” gets synced in the email column for the matching row in Spreadsheet B as well. Additionally, I want to make sure that any changes between the two sheets with matching email/phone fields both sync.

Is there a way to do this with a supported function, or would I have to use an extension?

Comment: Show us some sample data from Sheet1 and Sheet2.  Do the column names for all columns match between sheets?  Is it possible that the same number has two different email addresses between Sheet1 and Sheet 2?  Which takes precedence?

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Would you please clarify what you understand by "sync"? Do you expect that the data values in one or other of the spreadsheets will be permanently updated by the "sync", or that the "sync" will simply display the results of a `query` (or other function) without modifying any data values.

Answer (score 0):

There are many add-ons that let you synchronize two or more spreadsheets, such as [Sheetgo](https://workspace.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/sheetgo_connect_filter_merge_excel_csv/94172092257). Choose **Extensions > Add-ons > Get add-ons** to search for more.